# Display an image based on visited base url

Tags: php, html, css, image

Right, so this is a really simple - and likely somewhat stupid one.  Apologies in advance.

I've got a site that has three URLs that go to the same site.  Web server is apache, virtual host is done proper with StieAlias(es) so that if someone visits the site via URL1.com, the browser just sees URL1.com and then URL2.com, URL3.com - you get the idea.

Now the issue is the user wants to display a certain logo based on the base URL.  So if they do: 
    www.URL1.com --> logo1.gif
    www.URL2.com --> logo2.gif
    www.URL3.com --> logo3.gif

Totally elementary, but I've never done it before.  Site is PHP and I'm decent enough with PHP I suppose but I've got no idea even where to start on this one.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with some javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">;
  var host = location.host;
  // here we use the location to build the image name
  // for example, for stackoverflow the image name would be: `stackoverflow.com.jpg`
  document.getElementById('myImage').src = host+'.jpg';
</script>
```

and then in your html use:

```
<img id="myImage" src="" />
```

[Check this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leonardorb/Q8Smg/) that I've created for you. You can inspect the image element and check its source.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your logo file is located in the images folder with the file name **URL1-logo.png**.

## PHP

```
$mylogotoload = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

 echo '<img src="images/'.$mylogotoload.'-logo.png" />';
```

Comment: That totally worked too - thank you!  I ended up going with the JS answer, but this one nailed it too.